# Can I use PDSOE for "immediate" debugging?

Tags: debugging, openedge, progress-4gl

Using `ProEnv`, I have configured my computer to start the standard debugger in case my Progress application shows a message (press the "Help" button and in the callstack, click on "Debug"), this is done using this `ProEnv` environment variable:

```
DLC=C:\PROGRE~1\OpenEdge
```

My application is started, using the `-debugalert` switch.

However, now I'm starting working with PDSOE (Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge) and I would like to start up that debugger, in the mentioned case. I don't know how to do this, because PDSOE is based on Java technology (it's an Eclipse environment).

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to launch the PDSOE variant of the debugger is from within PDSOE, using a "Debug Configuration". If you've run the application this way, the PDSOE debugger is used regardless of whether you use breakpoints or the *<debug>* button.

If you run the application from a "Launch Configuration", then the *<debug>* button will launch the standalone debugger.

They're basically functionally equivalent but TL;DR you'll need to run the application using PDSOE's "Debug Configuration".

Answer (score 0):

Double click in the left margin of your source to set a break point (a small blue ball):

[image]

Then start your run configuration in debug mode:

[image]

You will be prompted to switch to debug perspective.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand the situation: I'm running an application, using `-debugalert` as a way to get to the debugger. When an alert-box is shown, I get the possibility to open the debugger. Currently this opens the debugger, linked to the `C:\Progressx86\OpenEdge\bin\prowin32.exe` application. I'd like to reconfigure my computer to start the PDSOE debugger instead.

Comment: Instead of trying to put the donkey behind the cart, translate the shortcut that you are using to launch your application to a launch configuration in PDSOE.

Comment: How? If `-debugalert` starts the wrong debugger, what starts the PDSOE one?

Comment: It's not about starting the debugger, it's about how you start your application. Instead of using a shortcut containing <dlc>bin/prowin32.exe -p myprogram.p - you want to transfer this data to a PDSOE launch configuration. Your application will work exactly the same as before but now when you click on 'Debug' in an alert-box you will be transferred to the PDSOE debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Add `DEBUGGER:INITIATE(). DEBUGGER:SET-BREAK().` anywhere in the code and execute the application (provided you've already run `prodebugenable -enable-all` from the `ProEnv` in Admin mode).